# Why getting following error in SSIS script?

Tags: ssis

I have simple script :

```
 public void Main()
    {
        // TODO: Add your code here
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;


        //MYCode

        Variables varCollection = null;
     

        string DestinationRoot = varCollection("User::DestinationRoot").Value.ToString();
        int MonthStartPosition = Convert.ToInt32(varCollection("User::MonthStartPosition").Value);
        int MonthLength = Convert.ToInt32(varCollection("User::MonthLength").Value);
        int MonthValue = 0;
        string MonthNameFormat = varCollection("User::MonthNameFormat").Value.ToString();
        string FolderName = string.Empty;
        string MonthwiseDirectory = string.Empty;

        if (MonthStartPosition > 0 && MonthLength > 0)
        {
            MonthValue = Convert.ToInt32(FileName.Substring(MonthStartPosition - 1, MonthLength));
        }

        if (FileName.Length > 0 && MonthValue > 0)
        {
            FolderName = new DateTime(1, MonthValue, 1).ToString(MonthNameFormat);
        }

        MonthwiseDirectory = System.IO.Path.Combine(DestinationRoot, FolderName);

        if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(MonthwiseDirectory))
        {
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(MonthwiseDirectory);
        }

        varCollection("User::DestinationFolder").Value = MonthwiseDirectory;

//Error 1 : also getting error here like 'varCollection' is a 'variable' but is used like a 'method'   

        Dts.TaskResult = Dts.Results.Success; //Error 2 
    }
```

But it gives error like :

> Error 1 : 'varCollection' is a 'variable' but is used like a 'method'
>
> Error  2:  'Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.ScriptObjectModel' does not contain a definition for 'Results' and no extension method 'Results' accepting a first argument of type 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.ScriptObjectModel' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\SSIS\dfac06a62ee9472bac783737af4957de\ScriptMain.cs 91  34  st_7c1dde41280d4efc996c50fead62bfa9

Comment: Is this line in a script task? Is it the only line within the `Main` block? can you please copy the entire script to make this clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, couple of things about how to use Stack Overflow.

1. Please **do not** post new questions when you can just ask the person who answered your question [How do I create a package that would copy all files from a given folder into a new folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7139172/how-to-create-ssis-package-which-copies-all-files-into-new-folder/7140168#7140168) about how to do this in C#. Also, *always* mention the **version** that you are using in the questions that you post.
2. Please **do not** post your questions in answer.

Anyways, here is the C# code for the VB.NET code that I posted. I have also updated the original answer to your other question [How do I create a package that would copy all files from a given folder into a new folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7139172/how-to-create-ssis-package-which-copies-all-files-into-new-folder/7140168#7140168) to include the C# code.

```
public void Main()
{
    Variables varCollection = null;
    Dts.VariableDispenser.LockForRead("User::SourceFilePath");
    Dts.VariableDispenser.LockForRead("User::DestinationRoot");
    Dts.VariableDispenser.LockForRead("User::MonthStartPosition");
    Dts.VariableDispenser.LockForRead("User::MonthLength");
    Dts.VariableDispenser.LockForRead("User::MonthNameFormat");
    Dts.VariableDispenser.LockForWrite("User::DestinationFolder");
    Dts.VariableDispenser.GetVariables(ref varCollection);

    string SourceFilePath = varCollection["User::SourceFilePath"].Value.ToString();
    string FileName = SourceFilePath.Substring(SourceFilePath.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1);
    string DestinationRoot = varCollection["User::DestinationRoot"].Value.ToString();
    int MonthStartPosition = Convert.ToInt32(varCollection["User::MonthStartPosition"].Value);
    int MonthLength = Convert.ToInt32(varCollection["User::MonthLength"].Value);
    int MonthValue = 0;
    string MonthNameFormat = varCollection["User::MonthNameFormat"].Value.ToString();
    string FolderName = string.Empty;
    string MonthwiseDirectory = string.Empty;

    if (MonthStartPosition > 0 && MonthLength > 0)
    {
        MonthValue = Convert.ToInt32(FileName.Substring(MonthStartPosition - 1, MonthLength));
    }

    if (FileName.Length > 0 && MonthValue > 0)
    {
        FolderName = new DateTime(1, MonthValue, 1).ToString(MonthNameFormat);
    }

    MonthwiseDirectory = System.IO.Path.Combine(DestinationRoot, FolderName);

    if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(MonthwiseDirectory))
    {
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(MonthwiseDirectory);
    }

    varCollection["User::DestinationFolder"].Value = MonthwiseDirectory;

    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer for Error 1 
As I'm using C# need to assign value like :

`Dts.Variables["DestinationFolder"].Value = MonthwiseDirectory;`

Answer (score 0):

The ScriptObjectModel class does not have a property called "Results" according to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.tasks.scripttask.scriptobjectmodel.aspx) MSDN page.

You'll need to post your code for a fully diagnosis.

Comment: Dts.TaskResult = Dts.Results.Success;
Above code is written in Vb.net I want to convert it into c#