# How to move a text file after importing the data using SSIS package?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have an SSIS (dtsx) package that imports data from a text file. How can I move the text file as a step within the SSIS package after importing the data? Is there a command line utility, or do I have to write a program to do this?

Answer (score 10):

You could use `File System Task` available in the `Control Flow` tab of the SSIS package to move files from one folder to another.

Here are some examples that show how to move files between folders.

[How do I move files to an archive folder after the files have been processed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6698075/how-do-i-move-files-to-an-archive-folder-after-the-files-have-been-processed)

[How do I create a package that would copy all files from a given folder into a new folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7139172/how-to-create-ssis-package-which-copies-all-files-into-new-folder)